# Offset a character in matplotlib captions

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, axis-labels, tex

Friends,

I have a plot axis with seventy ticks, representing a protein sequence. Since I can't fit that many letters on one line and have them legible, I have to stagger them, thus:

```
________________________________
P o A i I A o g e u n e f e t r
 l t x s s L n S q e c O L t e s
```

(The actual figure has much less space between the letters, they completely overlap if on one line.)

I want to emphasize certain ones of these, with asterisks or something:

```
________________________________
P o A i I A o g e u n e f e t r
 l t x s s L n S q e c O L t e s
*   *   * **   *       * *
```

But when I render this in Matplotlib using simple newlines, the asterisks are way lower than they need to be:

```
xLabels = [
        ['', '\n'][i%2]
        +sequence[i] 
        +['\n', ''][i%2] 
        +'\n' 
        +decorations[i]  
    for i in range(len(sequence))]
```

I know matplotlib supports TeX in its labels, and I know I can use \vspace{-1em} or something in LaTex, but I just can't get matplotlib to obey me. It keeps throwing parse errors, like this one:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 2345, in parse
  str(err)]))
ValueError: 
$ $
^
Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

(This was my attempt to put the decoration in TeX math mode, with the hope of adding a superscript. A possible complication is that many of the decorations are ' '.)

So, with that, my question is: is there a way to tell matplotlib's text renderer to move a character up a fraction of a newline? This needs to be simple to automate, as the whole program will generate nearly forty figures, each with potentially different decorations.

Comment: I'd start working with the `ax.text` function: "Add text in string `s` to axis at location `x`, `y`, data coordinates." Since it's in data coordinates, getting the right x-axis location won't be hard (reuse the tick locations). It would be nice to have a translation from font-size to y-height, but I bet you can get there without too much futzing.

Answer (score 1):

> ...is there a way to tell matplotlib's text renderer to move a character up a fraction of a newline?

I think you're on the right track.  You can change the vertical spacing in matplotlib with via the following Latex command, which you alluded to; however, I think you are going to want to work with `xticks` vs `xlabel` for your multi-line conditions.  Also, remember newline in tex is `\\`, not `\n`.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(plt.ylim()[::-1])
plt.xlabel(r"first line \\ \vspace{0.5cm}small space \\ \vspace{2cm}{more space}",fontsize=22)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, see [Text rendering With LaTeX](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)